# Building a simple chat client

Tags: java, chat, inputstream, outputstream

Im building a simple chat client which is only supposed to be able to send and receive messages.

Im using a server running on my own computer that sends back whatever message is sent to it, to all the user that's connected to the server.

When I send messages to the server by clicking my "send button", the server isn't sending back the message to me as it's supposed to. So either my output stream isn't working, or my listener for input messages isn't working but can't figure out what is wrong.

I might add, that i don't get any error messages/exceptions and connecting to the server works

```
public class Chatt extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea chattArea = new JTextArea();
    private JButton sendButton = new JButton("Skicka");
    private JLabel chattPerson = new JLabel("Du chattar med: ");
    private JTextField chattField = new JTextField(15);
    private Thread thread;
    private int port;
    private String ip;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private Socket s;


    public Chatt(String ip, int port){
        this.ip=ip;
        this.port=port;
        Konstruktor();
        }
    public Chatt(){
        ip="127.0.0.1";
        port=2000;
        Konstruktor();
        }
    public Chatt(String ip){
        this.ip=ip;
        port=2000;
        Konstruktor();
        }

    public void Konstruktor(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        chattArea.setSize(70, 50);  
        add(chattArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.add(sendButton);
        bottomPanel.add(chattField);
        sendButton.addActionListener(new sendListener());
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(chattPerson);
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        try {
            //s = new Socket("atlas.dsv.su.se", 9494);
            s=new Socket(ip, port); 
            } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection failed");
                } 
        catch (IOException e) {
                    }
        try{
        in= new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
        out= new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e){
                System.out.println("Host unknown");
            }
        catch(IOException e){

        }
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        setTitle("Connected to "+ip+" på port "+port);
        chattArea.setEditable(false);
        setSize(400, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void run() {

            while(true){
                System.out.println("tråden igång");
                try {
                    String temp = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(temp);
                    chattArea.append(temp);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

            }       
    }


    public class sendListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String chattString = chattField.getText();
                try {
                    out.writeUTF(chattString);
                    out.flush();
                    } 
                catch (IOException e1) {

                    }
                chattArea.append("Du: "+chattString+"\n");
                chattField.setText("");

            }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        //new Chatt("127.0.0.1", 2000);
        //new Chatt();
        new Chatt("127.0.0.1");
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you have pasted client code, and your issue seems to be with the server. You may require to post both.

Comment: Yeah it's only the clientcode, but this is a homework assignment and we've gotten the server from out teacher so im guessing it is working. Don't have access to the source-code to the server nor any documentation, but it's stated the the server sends back whatever message you send to it. Not supposed to call any specific server-methods

Comment: You are digesting most of the exceptions `catch(IOException e){

        }` are you sure you do not have any? - consider putting `e.printStackTrace()` in those.

Comment: added a printline after all the `catch(IOEXception e)` so pretty sure I don't have any

Comment: Looking at your code, it should work. Looks like an issue with the server. Create a test "echo server" for your purpose and validate your client.

Comment: If your teacher is attempting to make you test web services style applications then you should have gotten some form of documentation (i.e. what the request to the server should look like). I've run into Client/Server issues before because my request was not terminated with a blank line or something similar... See if your teacher can provide any insight into what kind of communications may be allowed or if the server will ever respond with error messages.

Comment: Are you sure the question didn't specify what signals an end of message? My guess would be the server is still waiting for you to finish. For example, a newline might be expected if the server uses readline

Comment: It can be that your teacher's chatserver is still waiting for input, although you have sent some bytes to it. Have you trying to sent either an EOF signal or another delimiter to signal the server that it should start processing the input bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the chatserver wasn't working correctly. I did build my own server and sending/reciving messages works fine, so nothing wrong with my code.